# Inserting thousands of records to Postgresql with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-rds

I will be creating an app which will receive for instance 100.000 XML records daily via API. My programming language will be Ruby on Rails and I am thinking of using Postgresql along with Amazon's RDS.

Then I will save these info to my database and send (POST) these data (via XML/API) to another web platform.

My question is, what is the best way to handle these kind of data? Do you think Amazon RDS is enough? or should I use some any other database rather than Postgresql?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I'am assuming the 100.000 XML data will be coming during the day between 10:00am - 10:00pm. This is from 1 customer. When the number of customer increases, I will need to scale. Because the operation will be like that;

1. XML data comes to my app.
2. I will save those data to my database (postgresql)
3. Then I will post those data to some other app.

At the beginning I can use Amazon's RDS with maybe 1 instance. But then I have to scale the app. I would like to create the database structure for the future scenario.

What would you recommend ? What tools should I use with RDS?

I am also thinking to differentiate between my UI (website) and API which means I will set up my UI in another server and API to another server. In the UI part I will have user auth, search users etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how fast you access the 100,000 records. If uniformly over the day, barely no load at all (about 1 transaction per second).

Instead if you are processing 100,000 records at once, you would need a substantial database to handle the load (at 50 records per second = 30 minutes).

The answer depends on how you use the database.